# Unable to send POST request in jmeter which have file upload and form data

Tags: html, angular, jmeter, http-post, performance-testing

When I submit the below data as POST request in JMeter, it displays the issue as

```
{"id":null,"errMessage":"Content type 'application/json' not supported"}.
```

I am using Parameters for JSON Data and File Upload for file uploading in JMeter. Also used HTTP header manager for content type info, but it's not working. Can someone help me to resolve the issue asap.

**Below is the Data:**

------WebKitFormBoundary1dSLJ0VIb34rDoYr

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Test.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

------WebKitFormBoundary1dSLJ0VIb34rDoYr

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonData"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"Comments":"AB","DocSrc":"Upload","Id":4997821,"Referrence":"rev","owner":"abcd","maxVersion":0,"Status":"New","Name":"Test.docx","UploadComment":"Desktop upload","TypeId":"5","Size":234,"fileUploadName":"Test.docx"}
```

------WebKitFormBoundary1dSLJ0VIb34rDoYr--

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header from the HTTP Header Manager along with the `------WebKitFormBoundary1dSLJ0VIb34rDoYr` separator
2. Tick `Use multipart/form-data` box in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

   [image]

In general if you're able to execute this request successfully in browser you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy your `Test.docx` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation so JMeter would be able to properly capture the request and generate relevant HTTP Request sampler configuration. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.